# How to block specific set of Ip addresses from an ISP

Tags: ip

When I type ipconfig in my windows pc I am able to see my Ethernet adapters local area connection IP address for eg : 193.168.1.13 . Now my problem is when I browse the internet I see that My ISP  provides different IP addresses for different sessions when I check for my IP. I am not happy with some ip addresses which my ISP provides to me . Is there a way to block my ISP from assigning those IP addresses . Can I write such a rule in firewall so that I can block that range of ip addresses ?
If possible then please tell me how to do that ?

Thanks in advance .